# MySQL: Get the higher number with the same id

Tags: mysql

I would like to select the highest number with the same ids.
Here is an example:

[image: CounterImage]

At first don't be panic! The "id" column is not my primary key. Well, how can I select the highest number. In this case the first line should not be appear.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Look up `MAX` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Select id,max(counter) as counter from TABLE group by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
SELECT id, MAX(counter) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Ok, but what if counter and id is the same? I would like to output both